# iterating over list of chars giving segment fault

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I am simply intreating over a list of chars and trying to print them.

```
char *name[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY", "SIG", "BML-O", "BHI", "KSU", "ORN"};
void function() {
    int i;
    //for (i =0; i<sizeof(name) / sizeof(char); i++) {
    for (i =0; name[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf ("%s \n", name[i]);
    }
}
```

When I use the first for loop(the one commented out) it prints out the list but has two items at the end that say `(NULL)` and gives a segment fault.  When I use the second for loop(the uncommented one), it prints everything but also gives a segment fault.

output:

```
RGS 
O 
NRGY 
SIG 
BML-O 
BHI 
KSU 
ORN 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I don't get any errors when compiling the code(`gcc ./learningC.c`) and if I comment out this function I do not get any error(it makes me think its this area of code thats the problem).  I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first style of loop, you need to use `sizeof(char*)`, not `sizeof(char)`.  The element of the array is `char*`, not `char`.

For the second style of loop, your array will only have a NULL at the end if you put it there:

```
char *name[] =  {"RGS", "O", "NRGY", "SIG", "BML-O", "BHI", "KSU", "ORN", NULL};
```

Comment: Your saying its not actually terminating the way I want it to?  But the commented out for loop is based on the sizeof, and it still has the same effect(seg fault). I don't understand how to iterate the list correctly.

Comment: it worked!!! Thanks Ned. I thought the size of char and char* was the same..Thanks a lot Ned!

Comment: @Error_404: Rather than using `sizeof(char *)`, if you write `sizeof name / sizeof name[0]` then you know it'll work no matter what type of array `name` is.

Comment: @caf wow..thanks..thats a lot easier. I will do that from now on.